# How can I override bootstrap $theme-color value in sass?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have to override bootstrap functions in my custom _variables.scss

I try with map-merge.

```
$theme-color: map-merge((primary, #333745 ));
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use merge-map, just set `$theme-colors` to a map:

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #333745
)
```

Make sure you include your custom variables file *before* the bootstrap variables file and you should be fine. Internally, it will do the following:

```
/* Set theme colors, !default means only update if undeclared */
$theme-colors: () !default;
/* Use map-merge to overwrite the standard colors with your colors */
$theme-colors: map-merge((
  primary: $blue,
  secondary: $gray-600,
  success: $green,
  info: $cyan,
  warning: $yellow,
  danger: $red,
  light: $gray-100,
  dark: $gray-800
), $theme-colors);
```

All of the bootstrap defaults are set using the `!default` flag, so you can override any value you need to by declaring it before you load the bootstrap sass code and it will honor your value over its own.